# How do I specify OR in DDMS

Tags: android, ddms

I know I can use regular expressions in DDMS window but can't figure out how. Suppose, I have filter 1 filtering by log label "A" and filter 2 filtering by log label "B" so what do I print in the ddms edit panel so I have both outputs from "A" and from "B" and nothing else?

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions inside the log panel,let's say you want to filter by tag,you write inside the tag filter:

```
^com.test.TestClassA$|^com.test.TestClassB$
```

It accepts simple boolean logic too,so even something along these lines would work:

```
com.test.TestClassA|com.test.TestClassB
```

No spaces between OR bars.

You can even do it directly from logcat top window,by appending a prefix for your desired scope:

```
tag:com.test.TestClassA|com.test.TestClassB
```

or the regex

```
tag:^com.test.TestClassA$|^com.test.TestClassB$
```

hope this is useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try with the regular expression:

```
^TAG_A$|^TAG_B$
```